# Using a .png as background and making winform transparent

Tags: c#, winforms, background, transparency

so I have been trying to do this for days, does anyone have an idea how to do this? I have a .png I want to set as the image of the application because I need the transparency on it but I can't seem to make the form transparent.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/x707uOR.png]

I need the yellow gone, in that image I have tried setting the transparency key + background key to yellow but it didn't work 100%..

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: if you are using .NET 4.5 then yourBitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.Yellow).

Comment: You need per-pixel alpha blending, not a color key.  Winforms does not support it by default, it is very incompatible with legacy Windows components that draw with GDI.  The text on your buttons will become transparent as well for example.  Plenty of web sites show you how to use it anyway, just google the term.

Comment: Hi Hans, I have got PPAB to work, however it's not showing via .png and when using .bmp it gives me an error "the bitmap must be 32ppp with alpha channel"? Any fix to get the .png version to work or getting the .bmp to 32ppp with alpha channel?

Comment: You cannot make windows form partially semitransparent. Means you cannot make any part of the form semitransparent like assigning opacity. you can find out the pixel in the image and replace that pixel to your assigned transparency key color.